# Как сократить запрос UPDATE, если входные данные - 4 координаты массива?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, update

Делаю запрос в базу данных

```
UPDATE `items` SET `status`=1 WHERE `x`=10 AND `y`=20
```

Это обновил одну строку.
А как обновить 100 строк, если входные данные - ЧЕТЫРЕ числа X=10,X=20,Y=20,Y=30, то есть для полей Х значением от 10 до 20 и Y от 20 до 30?
Нюанс в том , что структура базы данных такова:
сначала идет 100 строк, где значение поля X возрастает от 1 до 100 и Y=1, затем следующие 100 строк, где X также от 1 до 100, но Y=2, и так далее до Y=100, приложил скрин базы данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE items
SET status = 1
WHERE
  (x BETWEEN 10 AND 20) AND
  (y BETWEEN 10 AND 20);
```

Comment: хм, странно, не ожидал от BETWEEN!!)) Спасибо!